# Where can I find large sample of computer languages for Naive Bayesian Analysis

Tags: code-analysis, naivebayes

I am trying to analyse online code and want to use Bayesian Classification. However I need a fair amount of pre classified code as sample data.

Maybe the twenty or so top languages?

Does anyone know of such a corpus?

Comment: Are you simply trying to determine which language a chunk of text is?

Comment: Yes I am trying to determine which language a chunk of text is.

Comment: It might be easier to simply look for high probabilty clues.  "MOVE" is a pretty good sign it is COBOL.  "FORMAT" is a good sign it is FORTRAN.   "int *" is a good sign it is C or C++.   "int *" and "class" are good signs it is C++.  Why make this hard?

Comment: Regarding "pre classified" code: if you go to any on line code repository (e.g., SourceForge http://sourceforge.net), there's lots of code, and it will be pretty well categorized as to what (langauge) it is.

Comment: You can try with [Rosettta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code), but the problem here might be, that the algorithms are usually quite short (unlike actual software projects). Here is a [thread about what Github uses for language detection](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/156029/how-does-github-calculate-language-percentage-in-a-repo).

Comment: Yes, lot's of good stuff from both Rosetta and Github there. I think I may use Ira's suggestion of identifying language fingerprints and looking for them, although all the code in Rosetta will make it easier to identify what those are. - Cheers, Col

Answer (score 0):

there was a data set on Kaggle with questions from StackOverflow where the objective was to guess the tags related to the question.  That could require guessing the language of code samples (or just looking for keywords)
https://www.kaggle.com/c/facebook-recruiting-iii-keyword-extraction

Other possibilities searching through Github - since all that code is free and open.

StackOverflow itself shares its own data of all user contributed posts (anonymized)